# Finding solution of Differential Equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=y(1-\frac{y}{4})$ given $y=4$ when $t=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the Differential Equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y(1-\frac{y}{4})$$

First I was asked to find the constant solutions which are:

$$y=0,4$$

Now I am asked to use those solutions to find the solution to the DE with the initial values $y=4$ when $t=0$.

I started by dividing both sides by $y(1-\frac{y}{4})$:

$$\frac{1}{y(1-\frac{y}{4})}\frac{dy}{dt}=1$$

Then integrating both sides, and applying the substitution rule to the left side:

$$\int\frac{1}{y-\frac{y^2}{4}}dy=\int1dt$$

$$log(|y|)+\frac{4}{y}=t+C$$

But now I'm not sure how to rearrange the equation to make $y$ the subject.

Comment: Are you sure your integral for $\int \frac{1}{y - y^2/y}dy$ is correct?

Comment: Of course, if your initial condition involves $y=4$ then there is no integration needed and you are done.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the initial value conditions for a second, this is a separable first order DE. To solve for the family:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -\frac{y(y-4)}{4}\\
-\frac{4}{y(y-4)}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &= 1
\end{align}$$

By finding $A$ and $B$ such that $\displaystyle\frac{A}{y}+\frac{B}{y-4}=-\frac{4}{y(y-4)}$, we get:

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y-4}&=\int\mathrm{d}t\\
\ln\left|\frac{y}{y-4}\right|&=t+c_1\\
1+\frac{4}{y-4}&=c_2e^t\\
y&=\frac{4c_2e^t}{c_2e^t-1}\\
&=\frac{4e^t}{e^t+c_3}
\end{align}$$

As Michael points out in the comments, however, the condition $y=4$ when $t=0$ ruins the whole problem! :)

Comment: Yes, or $y(0)=4$ makes the problem easy with a constant solution!  Interestingly, if you let $y(0)=4-\epsilon$ then your $c_3$ is $O(\epsilon)$ and the resulting $y(t)$ is very close to constant for all time, intuitively converging to the constant $y(t)=4$ solution as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.